# Why is schema.rb not generated (properly) when running rake db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just started working through the Rails 3 tutorials so that I can develop a bit of familiarity with the framework, but I'm running into issues with the generation of schema.rb. My operating system is Windows 7 x64, Ruby 1.9.2, MySQL2 gem 0.2.6, Rails 3.0.3.

I have two migrations created, one for my lists:

```
class CreateLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
  create_table :lists do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.text :description

    t.timestamps
  end
end

def self.down
    drop_table :lists
  end
end
```

and one for my List items:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :type
      t.boolean :completed
      t.references :list

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :items
  end

end
```

Rake migrates successfully and the application works as expected, but schema.rb shows only:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20101126074332) do

# Could not dump table "items" because of following ArgumentError
#   invalid date  

# Could not dump table "lists" because of following ArgumentError
#   invalid date
```

Is anyone a bit more experienced with Rails that could offer advice on what might be causing the problem? Googling turned up nothing.

Comment: This probably won't be too helpful, but I tried your migrations with Win7 x32, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.3 and sqlite3 and it worked fine, so I'd put my money on the problem being with MySQL2.

Comment: It appears you're entirely correct, as it's dumped properly with the  SQLite3 adapter. Will try again on my Ubuntu box to see if it's a Windows-specific issue or something wrong with my MySQL install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the mysql 5.1 libmysql.dll as described in:

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/71

Answer (score 2):

Try `rake db:schema:dump`.

Comment: Results in the same output as indicated in the question, i.e: doing rake db:migrate after deleting schema.rb and dropping the db.

Comment: Phew thanks.  For some reason db:structure:dump always uses sql mode